# How to prevent PostgreSQL from rounding the output of double precision values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, type-conversion, precision, implicit-conversion

I have a table of locations with associated data combined from multiple providers. I had the provider id, the latitude and the longitude (both coordinates are `double precision`) as primary keys. But now, I would like to generate an id of type `varchar(50)` from the provider, the latitude and the longitude (both coordinates are double-precision values):

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET id = CONCAT(provider, '-', latitude, '-', longitude)
```

But when I try to set the new column as primary key

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

I get the error

> ```
> Key (id)=(2-53.69706-12.71236) is duplicated.
> ```

Turns out that there are indeed two entries with `id='2-53.69706-12.71236'`, but only one of them has longitude 12.71236. The other one has longitude 12.71235999999999. And while I can select them by these different longitudes:

```
SELECT
    longitude,
    to_char(longitude, '999D9999999999999999') AS longitude_to_char,
    data->>'ID' AS id_within_provider
FROM mytable
WHERE provider=2 AND latitude=53.69706 AND longitude=12.71236
```

```
longitude | longitude_to_char  | id_within_provider
 12.71236 |   12.7123600000000 | 42266
```

```
SELECT
    longitude,
    to_char(longitude, '999D9999999999999999') AS longitude_to_char,
    data->>'ID' AS id_within_provider
FROM mytable
WHERE provider=2 AND latitude=53.69706 AND longitude=12.71235999999999
```

```
longitude | longitude_to_char  | id_within_provider 
 12.71236 |   12.7123600000000 | 84742
```

the output longitude stays the same even if I try to convert it to char with an explicit precision. Funny enough, `to_char(12.71235999999999, '999D9999999999999999')` yields the original number while `to_char(longitude, '999D9999999999999999')` always yields the rounded number.

So I've got two different double precision values that I have no way to output in a different way, how they should be. What can I do? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What are you defining an `id` like this?  Just use a `serial` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to format double precision values into unique varchar values is nearly impossible. In short, you are fighting a losing battle.

The clear solution here is to use a composite primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY (provider, latitude, longitude)
```

Alternatively, you can use a `SERIAL` column as the primary key, and add a unique constraint to these columns (though I don't see why).

Comment: I want to prevent a composite primary key because I want to create another table where the columns would be the ID's of the locations (it should be a distance matrix).

Looks like a `SERIAL` column is a good fit for this, will wait if a better solution comes up.

What I don't get is: A double precision value has some sort of bitwise representation. So if these representations are different for X and Y then I should be able to print them out differently, shouldn't I?

Comment: It seems that there's no function immediately available to convert from double precision to byte array or similar. However, some people have added a simple extension to the database to perform the conversion that may be what you need. Not for the faint of heart, but take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46334478/convert-bytea-to-double-precision-in-postgresql